# Encoding "Non-ascii" characters in csv

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, siebel

Below is the code I've used to write to csv file (Host programming- Siebel escript)

```
var fp = Clib.fopen(FilePath, 'wu');
Clib.fputs("non-ascii text Ön Column1, Column2, Column3"+"\n", fp);
Clib.fclose(fp);
```

'wu' supports non-ascii chracters but this is resulted in invalid format, as excel appeared to fail to detect separator. So added additional code line to append command "sep=," in the beginning of the file.

```
Clib.fputs("sep=,\n", fp);
```

But this is still resulting in invalid format:

[image]

This looks even more worse. Not only formatting is gone, but also an extra "sep=," appears in the header. I tried fixing the "List separator" in control panel to ",", but changing it doesn't have any impact. 
Also when I used

```
var fp = Clib.fopen(FilePath, 'wt');
```

For the resulting file, excel was behaving normal. But it doesn't support the non-ascii text like "Ö".

Is there a way I could manage both "non-ascii" characters and "csv column formatting"?

Comment: The `sep=,` has no special meaning within a CSV file. So it is clear that this will not work. The issue occurs if a CSV file with other delimiters except tabulator is saved as `Unicode` (UTF-16 LE). Either you can use tabulator as delimiter or you have to save the CSV as `UTF-8`.

Comment: @AxelRichter, Could you please let me know how to encode with "UTF-8" in the above script?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe someone other knows how to do this.

Comment: @AxelRichter, but this is working in most of the machines and failing in some.

Comment: np. Thanks for your comments.